# How to check whether specific library is installed or not in my system?

Tags: linux, operating-system, installation

see i am working on `linux fedora`

Now suppose if i want to make sure that whether the library named as

`libmxml` is installed in my system or not then how can i know that ?

Comment: In what context do you want to know?

Comment: see befor installing some package we need to check whether its depended library are installed on our system or not ? so how can we check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, [`rpm` handles these dependencies for you](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html). If you need to hard-code a dependency to a package, then you can add a line like this to your `foo.spec` file:

```
Requires: pam
```

(This line is just an example; I stole it from a project I'm associated with; `pam` won't work for you.)

Comment: Something quick-and-dirty might be: `locate libmxml` ? It's not perfect, if someone downloaded the source but never installed it, it'll still show up, but if you're doing things by hand anyhow, you'll be prepared to handle those sorts of situations.

Comment: hey man its not perfect but my work is done with locate ..! thanks